# Converting data-frame into a dictionary by having the multiple lists?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, converters

I have a dataframe –mydata- consists of 500 rows something like this:

```
Id  Name    Score
R1  sam     76
R1  Sosan    8
..  …   … 
R4   jack   2
R4  Tom     76
R4   samy    8
R5  Check    9 
…    …
```

Now, I want to convert the dataframe into a dictionary so that the uniqe Ids become the keys and the rows of the uniques Ids become a list. For example, considering the above example, R1 should be a key and the inside of R1 we should have two lists, or for R4 we should have three lists etc. 
I have treid the below code, but it ignores the unique Ids :

```
mydictest= mydata.set_index('Id').T.to_dict('list').copy()
```

So, my desired output should be like this:

```
 {'R1': [['sam', 78],['Sosan',8]], 'R4': [['Jack', 2],['Tom', 76],    
 ['samy', 8]]}
```

Comment: Without meaning to sound terse, why do you want to do this? Usually doing complex data type manipulations like this should be avoided in favour of simple and tidy data forms.

Comment: Indeed, this dataframe is a validation set (I trained a model with another dataset) so I want to make a loop based on the key, and get the result (TP. TN, etc.) of each row for each key. Then I can plot the result based on the key.

Comment: Provide expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['R1', 'sam', 78], ['R2', 'rem', 65], ['R1', 'pem', 56]], columns=['Id', 'Name', 'Score'])
d = df.set_index('Id').to_dict(orient='split')

req_dict = {}
for ind, data in zip(d['index'], d['data']):
    if ind in req_dict:
        req_dict[ind].append(data)
    else:
        req_dict[ind] = [data]
print(req_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'R1': [['sam', 78], ['pem', 56]], 'R2': [['rem', 65]]}
```

Comment: The output of this code is also similar to the above code that I used. It ignores the Ids which are more than one, like R1 or R4. This code works if all the Ids are unique

Comment: How do you want your output to look like

Comment: I put my desired output in the question.

Comment: Is it possible to have a dictionary of data-frames? Something like the bove, but instead of the list in the dictionary, we put datas-frame (for each uniq Ides) which also include the columns's names.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to have dictionary of dataframes.